# schtasks single quotes in command

Tags: windows, escaping, quotes, windows-task-scheduler

I'm using schtasks.exe to create a scheduled task in Windows. The parameters include single quotes like this:

`schtasks.exe /create /tn Part1 /tr "powershell -c \"(new-object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('https://website/file.zip','C:\Path\to\file.zip')\"" /sc once /sd dd/mm/yy /st 00:00`

I know for embebed quotes I have to use `\"` however when I use single quotes I can see in GUI they had been replaced for normal quotes.

I would like a way to escape them.

Comment: Quoting the argument disables most of CMD's special characters (except "%") and also escapes white space in the `argv` process in schtasks.exe itself. The downside is that including double quotes in the argument requires escaping them with backslash. For convenience in this case, schtasks.exe translates single quotes to double quotes. But I don't think it provides a way to disable this.

Comment: You can create the task with PowerShell [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps) instead.

Comment: I'll try it, thanks.